# How can we solve this error in comparing two folders and storing those files with same name in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, directory

I am a beginner in Java and I wanted to create a program that compares two folders and can store the files with same name in an array. I want to access this array in another class to display the name of files.

```java
public int fileCompare(String path1, String path2) {
    int i, j, k = 0;
    flag = 0;
    File file1 = new File(path1);
    File file2 = new File(path2);
    File[] array_file1 = file1.listFiles();
    File[] array_file2 = file2.listFiles();

    int largerSize = array_file1.length > array_file2.length ? array_file1.length : array_file2.length;
    File[] equalFiles1 = new File[largerSize];
    File[] equalFiles2 = new File[largerSize];

    for (i = 0; i < array_file1.length; i++) {
        String n1 = array_file1[i].getName();

        for (j = 0; j < array_file2.length; j++) {
            String n2 = array_file2[j].getName();

            if (n1.equals(n2)) {
                flag++;
                equalFiles1[k] = array_file1[i];
                equalFiles2[k] = array_file2[j];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code contains the method for comparing two folders and returning the arrays. This array is then accessed using the below code.

```java
for (File file : c.equalFiles1) { // c is the object of previous class
    for (int i = 0; i < c.flag; i++) {
        row1[i] = file.getName();
    }

}
```

But the error was shown as

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
> Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

Comment: the error means that you've attempted to read beyond the upper bound of an array, if array has 3 elements, only index 0,1,2 are valid, attempting read array[3] will result in the exception provided.  I suggest hardcoding the array size to 128 until you get the logic of finding same files working. BTW row1[i] is where the exception is raised.

Comment: But the maximum size of array will only be the size of the folder(number of files in the folder) having lowest number of files, right?

Comment: yes, flag, should return the number of files that have the same name of the folders you're comparing, but until you debug the logic and avoid the exception (less frustration since you can count the files see whether flag returns the right number) just hardcode array to a large number. For test purpose, just copy three file in each folder, vary the file name for testing.

Comment: I tried to do it but still cannot figure out. The equal files are getting added to the array in fileCompare() method but row[] is showing the Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0".

Comment: print, folderpath1, make sure the folder exist and can be found, just methodically and strategically place print statement to verify the variables have the data you expect. Or user your IDE debugger and some brake pointers.  Simpler to use the first option of using print statements, System.out.println("at main>> folderpath1 =  " + folderpath1);

Comment: c.flag = c.fileCompare(folderpath1, folderpath2);  since this method return the number of equal files.

Comment: @MZM I have tried this but still the error occurs. I have print the equalFiles1[] array in demohack2 and the array prints successfully. Also c.flag prints successfully in demohack2. But the problem arises when I use this to add the name of the files in equalFiles[] to row array in demohack2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below compiles and prints the elements of array row1.  You can copy and paste in https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler  and select JAVA on the pulldown box, top right of screen. You still need to fix the logic to get meet the requirements

```
import java.io.*;
public class Main
{
     public static final String DIR_PATH1 = "./";     // replace with dir path
     public static final String DIR_PATH2 = "../../";
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        DemoHack1 c = new DemoHack1();
        String folderpath1 = DIR_PATH1;
        String folderpath2 = DIR_PATH1;
        
    
        c.flag = c.fileCompare(folderpath1, folderpath2);
        if (c.flag > 0) {  // make sure to void creating an array of size zero
            String[] row1= new String[c.flag];
            
            for (File file : c.equalFiles1 ) {
                for(int i=0; i < c.flag;i++){
                   row1[i]= file.getName() ;  
                   
                }
    
            }
          
            for(String r : row1){
                System.out.println("files in row>> "+ r )  ;  
                   
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("-----end -----");
         
    }
    
}   
class DemoHack1 {
    
        public File[] equalFiles1;
        public File[] equalFiles2;
        
        int flag;
        public int fileCompare(String path1, String path2) {
            int k=0;
            flag=0;
            File file1 = new File(path1);
            File file2 = new File(path2);     
            File[] array_file1=file1.listFiles();    
            File[] array_file2=file2.listFiles();
            int size1 = array_file1.length>array_file2.length ?    array_file1.length:array_file2.length;     
            equalFiles1 = new File[size1];
            equalFiles2 = new File[size1];
       
          for(int i=0; i< array_file1.length; i++){
            String n1=array_file1[i].getName();
            //System.out.println("n1>> " + n1);         // use print stmt to check the values
            
            for(int j=0; j <array_file2.length; j++){
                String n2=array_file2[j].getName();
                //System.out.println("n2>> " + n2);
                
                if (n1.equals(n2)) {
                    flag++;
                    equalFiles1[k]= array_file1[i] ;
                    equalFiles2[k] = array_file2[j];
                    k++;
                } 
            }
          }
     
         
          return flag;
        }
   }

Output:
 files in row>> DemoHack1.class
files in row>> DemoHack1.class
files in row>> DemoHack1.class
files in row>> DemoHack1.class
files in row>> DemoHack1.class
-----end -----
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in the second loop

```java
for (j = 0; j < array_file2.length; j++) {
    String n2 = array_file2[i].getName();
}
```

you put i instead of j hence when file1 length is greater than file2, the index got out of bound

and in demo2hack you init string row using c.flag
while c.flag is still 0

you should initialized your string row after calling c.compare file if you wanna use c.flag

Comment: Yes. Thank You. But still the array cannot be accessed. It shows "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
  at demohack2.main(demohack2.java:12) " error

Comment: edited my answer to answer the new error from demo2hack

Comment: Thank You. But I have called the c.fileCompare method(In line 8 in demohack2) right?

Comment: I have print the equalFiles1[] in demohack2 and the array prints successfully. Also c.flag prints successfully in demohack2. But the problem arises when I use this to add the name of the files in equalFiles[] to row array in demohack2. So c.flag is not null but still the error occurs.